# Default file extension for picture downloads on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, language, jpeg, file-extension

My google chrome will only save pictures as KanKan (then there's some Chinese: 图秀 or something)
How do I get it back to .jpeg as a default? (the drop-down menu only says "all files")

Answer (score 0):

Chrome decides on the files extension by what the online website tells Chrome it is. You cannot change this. By forcing a file extension you are assuming that all images are for example .jpg's. Chrome did not receive a file type from the server so it displayed "All Files" as a file type fall back. This is not an issue with Chrome but with the remote website. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)